# lower volume bound of submanifolds with small mean curvature integral data

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

$(M^n,g)$ is a smooth submanifold in $\mathbb{R}^p$ ,and $B_1$ is the unit ball centered in the origin 0.

Is there a $\epsilon >0$，
when assuming $\int_{M\cap B_1} |H|^n \leq \epsilon$, and the origin $0\in M$,

we have $vol(M\cap B_1)\geq 2^{-2019}\omega_n$ ?

where $\omega_n$ is the volume of unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Or are there any counterexamples ?

Comment: Could you please tell exactly what is meant by $H$? It seems that in case $p\ne n+1$ there is no canonical definition, at least according to the paper CONSTANT MEAN CURVATURE SUBMANIFOLDS OF HIGHER CODIMENSIONS
BY TOSHIYUKI MAEBASHI AND SADAHIRO MAEDA   https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.kmj/1138037199

Comment: H just means the mean curvature vector in the paper  CONSTANT MEAN CURVATURE SUBMANIFOLDS OF HIGHER CODIMENSIONS BY TOSHIYUKI MAEBASHI AND SADAHIRO MAEDA.

Comment: Actually, the n=2 case is simply following form the formula(1.2) in leon simon's CAG paper https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/cag/1993/0001/0002/CAG-1993-0001-0002-a004.pdf